# Is a monad is a map instead of a flatMap still a monad?

Tags: monads

I don't have a language-independent way to express the question but the Official™ definition of *monad* says that the bind operation takes a function that itself returns a monad instance.

However, all the handy examples I have of "monads" in the real world, the bound function returns a value of the underlying type, which the monad then wraps.

The difference is (if I am not completely lost) the same as the difference between `flatMap()` and `map()` in Scala collections.

Sources that I have found say

1. `map()` is an acceptable short-hand for `flatMap()`.
2. if it doesn't have a real `flatMap()`, it ain't a monad.
3. if it has `map()`, it's a *continuation*.

Obviously, I need an authoritative answer.

BTW, if it's (1), the universe of monads is huge -- pretty much every container class in every language has that.  If it's (2), then all the monads I have seen have been deliberately monads.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean. "all the handy examples I have of "monads" in the real world, the bound function returns a value of the underlying type" This is plainly not true. Start with the most handy monad, the `Maybe`. Then extend it to `List` where the bound function returns an empty list.

Comment: The language I happen to be using -- like the vast majority of all languages -- lacks a Maybe, and the List has a map, but no flatMap.

Comment: "Lacks a Maybe". You can define it yourself. "no flatMap". You can define it yourself. They don't become more or less monadic if they are missing from your language. You can also look at a language that has them (you are interested in language-independent stuff AFAICT).

Comment: I "can" write Duke Nukem 2000 myself too, but I wouldn't describe that as "handy".  All the examples I have *where other people have supplied me with code*, and not as examples but for my actual use, they provided map-style interfaces, not flatMap-style, and I am trying to learn the significance and implications thereof.

Comment: `Maybe` is probably ten lines of code, if your language is very verbose. People that didn't provide you with `flatMap` didn't provide you with a monad, that's all the significance that is.

Comment: If your language has a built-in notion of monad, but no flatmap-style interfaces, you better reveal what language it is. If it doesn't have monads built in, it is not clear how you expect to program in it monadic-style without having to define at least some monadic-style operations yourself.